# How to show image from Firebase show in viewpager

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Hello I'm newbie for firebase framework i try to retrive image from firebase storage but i see from tutorial [Firebase Ui](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/storage/README.md) I don't know how to use to my code , i try tutorial viewpager code from this [How to use viewpager show view with pageradapter](http://www.layer-net.com/%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%83%E0%B8%8A%E0%B9%89-viewpager-%E0%B9%81%E0%B8%AA%E0%B8%94%E0%B8%87-view-%E0%B8%94%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%A7%E0%B8%A2-pageradapter)

In my database to keep image like this array imagename ("991ec0d99212d58b7980100929cf7a260ae6a84a,95f1f9a33bf5b8736785dd218ecb79e6c41c6b30,a0a73f247296021d659fe1ab1cb64c019bf566bd")

and this firebase storage keep to keep image

[image]

[image: Imge array]

Here my code

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //add sample data
    ArrayList<Integer> picList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    picList.add(R.drawable.pic01);
    picList.add(R.drawable.pic02);
    picList.add(R.drawable.pic03);

    MyPagerAdapter mAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();

    //add View to Adapter
    for (int resource : picList) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_image,null);
        iv.setImageResource(resource);
        mAdapter.addView(iv);
    }

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

MypagerAdapter

```
  @Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    int index = views.indexOf(object);
    if (index == -1)
        return POSITION_NONE;
    else
        return index;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View v = views.get(position);
    container.addView(v);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView(views.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return views.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}


public int addView(View v) {
    return addView(v, views.size());
}

public int addView(View v, int position) {
    views.add(position, v);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    return position;
}

public int removeView(ViewPager pager, View v) {
    return removeView(pager, views.indexOf(v));
}

public int removeView(ViewPager pager, int position) {

    pager.setAdapter(null);
    views.remove(position);
    pager.setAdapter(this);

    return position;
}


public View getView(int position) {
    return views.get(position);
}
```

I hope everyone can help to solve my problem i try for 1 week can't do this

thank you

Comment: please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56769999/i-cant-load-images-retrieved-from-firebase-into-a-viewpager